# Change Default Directory in SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, editor

Despite it being an older editor, I still use Microsoft's SharePoint Designer 2007 for local development, I guess because I'm used to the layout, color coding, and ease of use.  I know there are other development packages like Joomla! and Drupal, and I know there are lots of editors that recognize PHP code and such, but I prefer SP Designer 2007 simply because I've used it since it first came out and I like it.

However, I have never figured out how to change the default directory.  Upon opening the editor, the default folder it shows is located at `c:/users/owner/documents/my web sites/`.  How would I go about changing that to a different path, like `c:/webpages/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Regedit  ( If you have never used regedit make sure you back up your keys before making changes.)
<kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> and search for my web sites.
Change the keys that shows `c:/users/owner/documents/my web sites/ to c:/webpages/`
Open `Sharepoint` designer and when you open or save a file it should direct you there.